# Block by file type, but just file extension using MDaemon

Tags: email-server, spam-filter, mdaemon

I've had users sending copyrighted files (songs, videos) to each other over email. I blocked the file extensions .mp3 etc. What some users have done is to rename files to .doc etc.

I cant block .doc etc filetypes because they are needed for day-to-day work.

I'm using MDaemon 12 mailserver, Does anyone know how to make it block these attachments? I've been working on some content scanning for filetype code, but was wondering if there is a already made solution?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a business environment, this is the point where Management should be involved.

Not every problem has a technical solution and repeat offenders that are exposing the company to risk of legal liability or security vulnerability should have their employment terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your advice. Normally I would agree with you that this is a management problem. But that does not work for me in this case.

I have written a MDaemon plugin which does the file type checks on email attachments.

If anyone else has same problem look at my filter on SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mdspamfilter/) and download MDSpamP.zip. Simply compile and put MDSpamP.dll as a plugin SpamFilter. You can customize it using the Python md_spam_filter.py file.

I am releasing this to the community as Open Source under BSD license.